# gitlab-shell ssl cert issues

Tags: ruby, ssl, ssl-certificate, gitlab

I've tried now for several hours te set up gitlab and especially gitlab-shell. After being trolled by the documentation I found a sample config, that fitted my needs, but I get an API 500 error :

`Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 500
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.`

To explain my current setup:

```
#/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
user: git
gitlab_url: https://[myfqdn]/
http_settings:
  ca_file: "/etc/gitlab-ssl/git-mydomain-chain.pem"
  ca_path: "/etc/gitlab-ssl"
  self_signed_cert: false
repos_path: "/home/git/repositories/"
auth_file: "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"
redis:
  bin: "/usr/bin/redis-cli"
  namespace: resque:gitlab
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
log_level: INFO
audit_usernames: false
```

In the `/etc/gitlab-ssl` directory are two files:
 * my privatekey `git-mydomain-key.pem` 
 * the combinded public key and CA-key git-mydomain-chain.pem

In addition I added the ca-key to the ca-certificates (it's a cacert signed one).

Can anyone help me and tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with `gitlab`. This is pure YAML parser (`Psych` in your case) error.

Line 5 column 3 is:

```
ca_path:
⇑ HERE
```

That said you have a strange unterminated string right above:

```
                                                 ⇓⇓⇓ WTF?!
ca_file: "/etc/gitlab-ssl/git-mydomain-chain.pem #This file contains my public key and the ca key
```

Remove everything after hash (inclusive) and close the string quotes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I removed the comment and added the quotes. With the result that I'm back up with an API Error

Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 500
gitlab-shell self-check failed

Comment: Update the question with new info.